# Adding attachment to the Email using Rest API

Tags: attachment

I am calling API EmailMessage and storing email-related content, Now I have attachments in email so how can I set it on a particular email using REST API?

What I am using is this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/EmailMessage

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sagar Virpara

Comment: How about [Attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Attachment) and provide ParentId as the Inserted email id

Comment: Do you mean OwnerId  ?

Comment: Looks like documentation is flawed(https://i.imgur.com/hKVVWbC.png)

When you provide parentId it works(https://i.imgur.com/l2lA4Br.png)

Comment: So ParentId has to be of EmailId ?

Comment: I am getting Parent ID: id value of incorrect type: 0052v00000WF1TVAA1

Comment: The id you are passing seems to be a user ID. The parentID should be a whatid not whoid.

Comment: Now I am able to insert it but how can I send Actual Image or other file with it ?